# Erro ao chamar método android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, método

Estou tendo erro de: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

ao tentar chamar um método, conforme o código abaixo:

```java
    public void return_profile_infos(String result_id) {
        idasync=null;
        idtxt.setText(result_id);
        idasync=result_id;
        p.hide();
        verifylogin();
    }

    public void verifylogin() {
        if ((idasync!=null))   {
        tst1 = getString(R.string.act_profile_wlcm_msg);
           Toast.makeText(Profile.this,tst1+", id= "+ idasync,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
        startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        }
    }
```

O erro acontece quando eu tento chamar o método `verifylogin()` à partir do `return_profile_infos` .
Estou há horas tentando e não consigo resolver, o meu app dá a mensagem de que o app parou.

Desde j[a agradeço quem se propor a ajudar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Verifique o objeto "tst1" no método verifylogin(), veja se há algum valor atribuído a ele.

Comment: verifique também se os objetos de edit estão instanciados corretamente com o layout

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Dei mais uma pesquisada a respeito e verifiquei que o erro ocorre devido à destruição do fragmento que o Toast utiliza para executar, no meu contexto, percebi que seria mais viável retirá-lo do meu código ao invés de consertar este problema.